# Python ZSI web service giving 404 Service not found error

Tags: python, web-services, soap, zsi

I have made a python SOAP webservice using the ZSI Framework. I am trying to call the service from the browser through link http://localhost:8181/WebService. But I am getting the 404 Service not found error. What can be the problem? I am able to access the service through an opensource SOAP Client.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from that url? I don't think the soap client hits the url using a HTTP GET.

Comment: Basically I want to invoke the method on the web service. The method returns the server version. I am not sure how to achieve this. i have tried to open this link using HTTP POST through Postman - Chrome Plug-in. In that case I get a fault string "Processing Failure"

Comment: You might need to use a library like curl or python requests to fashion a POST request, sending the soap message. You could use something like wireshark to capture the packets sent, when you use the SOAP client you mentioned and then you will know what the service is expecting and you can copy that.